# Remove a label with function arguments tkinter

Tags: function, python-3.x, tkinter, arguments, label

I am trying to remove a label in tkinter, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
    self.label(text='message')
    self.label.grid(row=1,column=1)
    def removelabel(labelname):
          labelname.grid_remove()

    removelabel(self.label)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to save a reference to the widget, which requires to to create the widget and lay it out in two steps:

```
self.label = tk.Label(...)
self.label.grid(row=1, column=1)
...
def removelabel(label):
    label.grid_remove()
...
removelabel(self.label)
```